# Unexpected and unwanted div element in return from Spring RestController

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I return an object instance of the following class from a Spring RestController method.

```
package x

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@XmlRootElement(name = "invoices")
public class Invoices implements Serializable {

    private Info info;

    private Set<Customer> customers = new HashSet<>();

    private List<Invoice> invoices = new ArrayList<>();

    public Info getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(Info info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "customer")
    public Set<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

    public void setCustomers(Set<Customer> customers) {
        this.customers = customers;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "invoice")
    public List<Invoice> getInvoices() {
        return invoices;
    }

    public void setInvoices(List<Invoice> invoices) {
        this.invoices = invoices;
    }
}
```

The Controller method has the signature;

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/invoice", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/xml; charset=UTF-8")
```

This returns an XML with an unexpected div element and an attribute named slick_uniqueid on the top element. How do I get rid of this, and where does this come from?

```
<invoices slick-uniqueid="3">
<div>
<a id="slick_uniqueid" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is this the answer (response) from your controller? looks like you are using some javascript framework called `mootools` which adds this attribute

Comment: Doh. My bad. The raw response from the server does not include this attribute. It's chrome that modifies the XML slightly when it displays it in-browser. Strange, never noticed that before!

Comment: Well, at least now, "the Google"  knows more about slick-uniqueid. Did I say slick-uniqueid? slick-uniqueid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this myself. The raw response from the server does not include this attribute, nor the extra element. It's chrome that modifies the XML slightly when it displays it in-browser. The attribute and element is not there if I do a 'view source' either. Strange. I have never noticed that before

Comment: It is probably some extension you have installed in Chrome.